# how to match data from a 2 arrays and create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i have the following array

```
response=[
    {            
        "mId": "4a993417-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7",
        "title": "test2",
        "score": "4",
        "id": "91ce873f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
    }
]
[
    {            
        "mId": "7896548-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c855d7fda6d7",
        "title": "discussion",           
        "score": "18",        
        "id": "91ce873f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
    }
]
[
    {           
        "mId": "20d78952-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7",
        "title": "test",         
        "score": "1",          
         "id": "7777777f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
    }
]
```

i then have another array that looks as follows

```
mixture=[{"id":"4a993417-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7","name":"flour","description":"10g sold"}]
[{"id":"20d78952-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7","name":"teabag","description":"stock arriving"}]
```

how do i check the mId from the response array onto the corresponding array from mixture to get back the name
so my new array should look as follows

```
newArray=[{
"name":"flour"
"mId": "4a993417-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7",
            "title": "test2",
            "score": "4",
            "id": "91ce873f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
}]
[{ "name":"flour"
           "mId": "4a993417-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c535d7fda6d7",
            "title": "discussion",           
            "score": "18",        
            "id": "91ce873f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
}]
[{         "name":"testbag"
           "mId": "7896548-3dae-4a85-bb2e-c855d7fda6d7",
            "title": "test",           
            "score": "1",        
            "id": "7777777f-6e58-4c30-86d4-4eb7f200640e"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you write your response and mixture arrays correctly, you can achieve it by using a combination of [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const newArray = response.map(item => {
    const mix = mixture.find(mix => mix.id === item.mId);
    if (mix) {
        item.name = mix.name;
    }
    return item;
})
```